# SQL calculation limited to 6 decimal points

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, decimal-point

I am trying to calculate the percent of total using partition over, and need the result to calculate beyond 6 decimal places. I have millions of records, so I need the calculation to extend beyond 6 decimal places to sum to 100% of total.

I have tried to cast the result as decimal with 18 places, but I am still getting all zeros beyond the 6th decimal place.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT
     ISNULL(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0)  / SUM(NULLIF(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) ) OVER (PARTITION BY c.calyr) AS percentoftotal
    ,CAST(ISNULL(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0)  / SUM(NULLIF(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) ) OVER (PARTITION BY c.calyr) AS DECIMAL(38,18)) AS percentoftotal
FROM c
```

[screenshot of result]

[image: 1]

Update: Thank you for the responses! I have tried casting everything as decimal (the numerator, denominator, and result) and am still getting all zeros past the 6th decimal place. Perhaps the issue is with the Partition by?

```
CAST(CAST(ISNULL(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) AS DECIMAL(38,18)) / CAST(SUM(NULLIF(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) ) OVER (PARTITION BY c.calyr)as decimal(38,18)) as decimal(38,18)) AS percentoftotal
```

Comment: tag your database , also what are datatype of your columns , plus add sample data

Comment: You're calling `CAST()` on the result of the division; after the division has already happened. This means that any rounding has already happened, the information you want to retain has already been lost. Try casting THEN dividing.  `CAST(x AS DECIMAL(38,18)) / y`

Comment: What is the datatype/precision of `c.PaidOriginal`?

Comment: jmoerdyk the data type of c.PaidOriginal is numeric (dollars)

Answer (score 3):

cast first or second number to the precision you want before deviding:

```
SELECT
     ISNULL(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0)  / SUM(NULLIF(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) ) OVER (PARTITION BY c.calyr) AS percentoftotal
    ,CAST(ISNULL(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) AS DECIMAL(38,18)) / SUM(NULLIF(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) ) OVER (PARTITION BY c.calyr)  AS percentoftotal
FROM c
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d00097299a86be5e8dfbe392983acb9b)*

Comment: I have tried casting the numerator, denominator, and result all as decimal and am still getting zeros beyond decimal 6.

Comment: ,CAST(CAST(ISNULL(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) AS DECIMAL(38,18)) / CAST(SUM(NULLIF(SUM(c.PaidOriginal),0) ) OVER (PARTITION BY c.calyr)as decimal(38,18)) as decimal(38,18)) AS percentoftotal

Comment: @Heidi , it works perfectly for  me , see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d00097299a86be5e8dfbe392983acb9b)*

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and finally was able to get it to work.  I had to lower my precision.  Everything else, as you mentioned, would stop after 6 and just add 0's.
For Example

```
convert(numeric(30,8), PaidOriginal)
```